# ActiveMQ Consumers created from unknown source

Tags: tomcat, jms, activemq-classic

I have a HTTP proxy that converts the HTTP request into JMS message (having only the request URL)

A program reads from this JMS queue and fires the HTTP request, gets the response and puts the response back in new queue for consumer.

The response is coming fine back to the queue. The problem is there are many consumers waiting on the queue and nobody gets the message. I am not able to track the source from where these consumers are created?

The consumer I created is left blocked on the queue.

Answer (score 0):

to debug this, you might take a look at the consumers in AMQ web console...otherwise, if you create a separate queue per client ([as described here](http://activemq.apache.org/how-should-i-implement-request-response-with-jms.html)), then you should only have a single consumer per queue...